# связь prometheus и grafana

Tags: linux, prometheus, grafana

Я пытаюсь подключить prometheus к grafana[image: Скриншот настроек Prometheus]

Но выдает такую вот [ошибку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69HYU.png):

> Post "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query": dial tcp [::1]:9090: connect: connection refused — There was an error returned querying the Prometheus API.

Вместо localhost пробовала чисто на всякий вбить 127.0.0.1, но лучше не становилось. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Логичный вопрос — почему вы вообще решили, что на адресе localhost:9090 должно что-то быть? Если вы предполагаете, что на этом адресе должен быть Prometheus, то что вы предприняли для того, чтобы Prometheus на этом адресе действительно был?

Comment: @andreymal я установила на виртуальную машину Prometheus, организовала проброс портов через 9090 и получила на http://localhost:9090 вроде как работающий Prometheus

Comment: А Grafana где установлена?

Comment: @andreymal тоже на виртуальной машине (и также проброшена через 3000)

Comment: На той же самой или на другой?

Comment: @andreymal на той же самой

Comment: Просто на виртуальной машине? Без контейнеров или какой-нибудь ещё хренотени?

Comment: @andreymal просто, вообще без всего

Comment: Тогда по идее должно работать. Возможно, вы что-то не договариваете, но у меня нет идей что ещё спросить